# Compare duplicate rows in a dataframe to determine Pass/Fail

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that may contain many similar data points within it. Removing duplicates is easy, but I would also like to take the same tests with different results and AND them into a single pass/fail result.

Example data

```
                                         
SW      Group   Name                      Result   
0.1     Group1  Test1_30Hz                Pass
0.1     Group1  Test1_30Hz                Fail
0.1     Group1  Test2_60Hz                Pass
0.1     Group1  Test3_120Hz               Fail
```

I.e. I would take find items with matching values in columns=[SW,Group,Name] and then AND the result columns

Example Output

```
                                         
SW      Group   Name                      Result    
0.1     Group1  Test1_30Hz                Fail
0.1     Group1  Test2_60Hz                Pass
0.1     Group1  Test3_120Hz               Fail
```

I can easily do this by changing the data structure to be not a datafame and just comparing them myself. But I'm trying to learn how to better manipulate data within a dataframe itself, and it always seems harder than I want it to be.

So in addition to the main problem, is there any suggestions for what to learn to be better at manipulating my data?

Comment: Does standard and logic apply? Any 'Fail' in the group will result in an overall 'Fail' result?

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, this means that any fails must mark it as a total failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df.groupby(["SW", "Group", "Name"], as_index=False)["Result"].apply(
    lambda x: "Fail" if "Fail" in x.values else "Pass"
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
    SW   Group         Name Result
0  0.1  Group1   Test1_30Hz   Fail
1  0.1  Group1   Test2_60Hz   Pass
2  0.1  Group1  Test3_120Hz   Fail
```

Comment: This definitely works and makes sense to me. I still feel like every time I want to do something with a dataframe I have to use a different method to index/compare/sort the values. But I suppose that's the cost of the more complex data structure.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
new_df = (
    df.sort_values('Result')
        .drop_duplicates(['SW', 'Group', 'Name'])
        .sort_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    SW   Group         Name Result
1  0.1  Group1   Test1_30Hz   Fail
2  0.1  Group1   Test2_60Hz   Pass
3  0.1  Group1  Test3_120Hz   Fail
```

`sort_values` ensures that a `Fail` result (if one exists) appears first in so when `drop_duplicates` removes all entries but the first it will keep the `Fail` row.